# Read local file in Intellij IDEA JavaEE web application deployed with tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, web-applications

I have a simple JavaEE web application project in Intellij and I need to read a file in `src.main.resources` folder. Follow is a screen shot of what my project looks like.

[image]

I need to return the context of **data.txt** file in the `getData()` function. Current method does nothing but return **"Error"** to the index.jsp and throw a `NoSuchFileException`. I tested using following paths but result is the same.

```
"data.txt"
"/data.txt"
"src/main/resources/data.txt"
"/src/main/resources/data.txt"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to either use the absolute path or the path relative to the Tomcat working directory (or change Tomcat working directory inside the server startup script). The better option could be to read it from the classpath instead.

Comment: Can you please show me how to do that relevantly to my environment?

Comment: I'm sure you can find hundreds of answers how to do that, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create your java project structure correctly, place HelloWorld.java under src/main/java.

Put your resources under /src/main/resources.

Load the resources with:

```
.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName)
```

Comment: Complete solution I found is added as another answer. But your answer led me to it hence I'm marking this as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("get data");
    String newMessage = "error";
    String fileName = "abc.txt";
    try {
        newMessage = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\kalingay\\IdeaProjects\\SpringMVCCrudApp\\src\\main\\resources\\" + fileName)), "UTF-8");
        System.out.println("out--->" + newMessage) ;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception-->" + e);
    }
```

Comment: Using relative paths is not a good practice @KalingaYapa. This would result in numerous errors when deployed elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
 System.out.println("get data");
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = HelloWorld.class.getResourceAsStream("kky.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            out.append(line);
        }
        System.out.println(out.toString());
        reader.close();
        System.out.println("out--->" + out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception-->" + e);
    }
```

Make Sure HelloWorld class and kky.txt in same folder ... :) :) This will help you :) :)

[image]

Using Relative Path .... :) :) try this one

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @D00de I got together a complete solution as follows.

First thing to do is reorganize the project as shown in the image. Classes should go in `src.main.java.*` and resources should go in `src.main.resources.*`

Then to access the file, use following code.

```
URI uri = HelloWorld.class.getClassLoader().getResource("metadata/data.txt").toURI();
out = String.valueOf(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(uri)));
```

[image]